# PLS-00382 with Oracle Objects and For loop

Tags: oracle, collections, oracle11g, user-defined-types

Below I'm trying to group up my collection and the makes some calls to other functions/stored procedures with the data. For some reason I can't figure out why the error is saying **PLS-00382** expression is of wrong type. I didn't include the call but I get the same problem if I try to assign **Recippayment** to **Oupayment**. Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Over_Under_Payment AS OBJECT
(
    Demoid            NUMBER,
    Paymentamount     NUMBER,
    Month     DATE
)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OVER_UNDER_PAYMENT_LIST as table of OVER_UNDER_PAYMENT


PROCEDURE Pass_Payments(Listofpayments IN Over_Under_Payment_List) IS

    Oupayment Over_Under_Payment;

BEGIN
    FOR Recipient IN (SELECT Demoid
                      FROM   TABLE(CAST(Listofpayments AS Over_Under_Payment_List))
                      GROUP  BY Demoid) LOOP
        FOR Recippayment IN (SELECT *
                             FROM   TABLE(CAST(Listofpayments AS Over_Under_Payment_List))
                             WHERE  Demoid = Recipient.Demoid) LOOP
            Oupayment := Recippayment;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mistake is the assumption that a row returned into `Recippayment` in your `SELECT * FROM TABLE(Listofpayments)` loop is an `Over_Under_Payment` object.

The actual type of `Recippayment` is a [record variable of the row type returned by the cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155), in other words a record which has the same field names as your `Over_Under_Payment` type.

One way to get the procedure to work is to reconstruct your objects in the inner loop:

```
    FOR Recippayment IN (SELECT Over_Under_Payment(Demoid, Paymentamount, Month) AS Payment
                         FROM   TABLE(CAST(Listofpayments AS Over_Under_Payment_List))
                         WHERE  Demoid = Recipient.Demoid) LOOP
        Oupayment := Recippayment.Payment;
    END LOOP;
```

This way, the type of `Recippayment` is a record type with one field of type `Over_Under_Payment` which I've chosen to name `Payment`.  In the loop body, we fetch the object out of the record.

Incidentally, you can replace `CAST(Listofpayments AS Over_Under_Payment_List)` with just `Over_Under_Payment_List`, as `Listofpayments` is already of type `Over_Under_Payment_List`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I couldn't find anything on this. The one annoying thing is that you have to list every attribute/property you have and can't just say Select *. You know of anyway around this since I have 25 properties for this type and I'll prob use this loop a lot?

Comment: @Dante: sorry, I don't know of any way around this.  Oracle collections can be frustrating to deal with, as I'm sure you're finding out right now!